# Xcode crashes on Autocomplete when working on a subclass of IKImageBrowserView

Tags: swift, xcode7, ikimagebrowserview

I'm working on a project by trying to subclass Apple's IKImageBrowserView. Everytime when Xcode shows the autocomplete suggestions which has something to do with this class the IDE crashes, both on my MacBook and my iMac. Am I doing something wrong? Is it because this class is not Swift-ready (it's not documentated for Swift yet)? Or do I miss something?

Does anyone have the same problem? If so, how to avoid this?

THX in advance